# copying large object member variable or calling it a lot of times

Tags: c++, performance

Consider the class below and assume that the myVector variable will store a very large vector of integers

```
Class MyClass {

Private: 

std::vector<int> myVector;

Public:

std::vector<int> GetVector();  
// some other functions that allow me to set myVector
};

std::vector<int> MyClass::GetVector() {

return myVector;
}
```

In some function I need to do some computations using the myVector variable of a MyClass object.

Is it better to make of copy of this very large vector, like this

```
int function (MyClass object) {


std::vector<int> vector = object.GetVector();



for (int i = 0 ; i<vector.size();i++){

// Do something using vector[i]

};
return 0;

}
```

Or to call every time, like this

```
int function (MyClass object) {




for (int i = 0 ; i<object.GetVector().size();i++){

// Do something using object.GetVector()[i]

};
return 0;

}
```

or does it not matter in the end?

Comment: Personally, if you only need to read the data I would get a `const&` to the vector.  Saves the copy and enforces read only.

Comment: IMO, returning a *copy* of the vector is the basis of your performance issues.  However, only profiling will tell the truth.

Comment: Whether performance matters or not is up to the User or if you are missing timing events.  Get the code working correctly and robustly before worrying about performance.

Comment: This is not just a performance issue.  What if you really want to work with the actual, original vector, and not a copy?  A lot of bugs occur with code such as yours, especially when it comes to using iterators and expecting that the iterators being used are iterating over the original vector, when actually you're iterating over copies of your vector (thus iterator runtime bugs).

Comment: I'm new: is it customary to edit the question based on the comments and answers of the users, but thereby making these comments seem weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to avoid pass-by-value for huge object. You should pass-by-reference instead. Because it appears you modify `object` inside `function` so you need to pass non-const reference, otherwise it should be `const MyClass &object`

```
int function (MyClass &object)
```

Also in `GetVector` you should just return a reference to `myVector`, no need to return-by-value.

```
    std::vector<int> & MyClass::GetVector() {
        return myVector;
    }
```

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes it should return reference as well

Comment: I don't need to modify object, i just need to access elements of myVector

Comment: so your comment `// Do something using vector[i]` is a bit misleading. If you don't modify the object then your prototype should be `int function (const MyClass &object)`

Comment: yes you are right, I should have put 'const' in the prototype.

Comment: @Morten -- See my comment above.  You need to clarify what you mean by "access elements of myVector".  The original vector, or a copy of the vector?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For my purposes it could have been a copy. But i see now thanks to the answers and comments that in any case its better to pass by reference

Answer (score 2):

If it is really large first and you will not be writing to the object or the vector inside function pass the Object by refrence

```
int function(const MyClass &object)
```

And also create a const method inside your class

```
const std::vector& getVector()
```

Then you can copy a reference over in the function with calling the vector and you won't have to call `.getVector()` constantly

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, making a copy and then iterating through it should be better if you want to choose between the two options you present. But, in fact, it would be a whole lot better to not return the vector itself but a (constant) reference to it.

A good rule of thumb is to use passing by `const&` instead of passing by value when possible if working with compound types, especially containers. Just remember to not use the `const vector&` after the `MyClass` object is destroyed. If not already out of scope, it will become a so-called dangling reference where access will result in undefined behaviour. This is the most important thing to watch out for when using `const&` instead of copying something.

If you need something to be alive even after the containing object dies, you should consider using a `std::shared_ptr<T>`. It will keep the object alive until no one needs it anymore, meaning nothing referring to the managed object remains (simplified).